# PHP echos file as text instead of binary on server

Tags: php, file, text, binary, response-headers

I have written a PHP page which reads a file and does echo it after adding some headers:

```
header('Content-disposition: filename="' . $fname . '"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-type: $AttachFileType");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($ffullname));
echo file_get_contents($ffullname);
```

This piece of code does well on local test, but when porting to the server, the response is not as expected. For example when I want to retrieve a png file, I get the below image on local test:

[image: local output]

while server test outputs this one:

[image: server output]

As I have investigated, the only difference of them is 4 additional headers on server response. Local test response headers:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-disposition: filename="attachment_hrmstotal_generalskills_6.png"
Content-Length: 2401
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: png
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 04:45:02 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Pragma: public
Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu)
```

and server response headers are these:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-disposition: filename="attachment_hrmstotal_generalskills_1.png"
Content-Length: 184450
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: png
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 04:40:56 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: public
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

The last four headers is the difference. What is the problem, its reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content-type should be `Content-type: image/png`

Comment: Yes. But how does it work on local server? Is this due to server config differences?

Comment: Because on your own pc the system knows png as an image file extension which should be opened as an image. But here in your script you send binary headers without precising, the file is opened as is. Environnement is a key point when developing, something won't work online only because it worked on local.